Woocommerce - Variable products filtering with in stock and size
I stumbled across this on my website and it does not make much sense. When someone applies the in stock status it shows all products which are in stock which is okay as they have available variant but when for example the user applies size L it shows again all products with no difference applied to the displayed products. I've read that this is the expected Woo behavior when trying to filter in stock products with another attribute. I've searched for possible solutions but was not able to find a working one for my case and currently I am using this:
 function check_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
   if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
  return false;
 }
  return $active;
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active','check_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );

At least not to confused the users when something is not available but is there a solution to modify the query so when someone clicks on size in my case to see only the products available with that size. I am not hiding the out of stock products in my store as we have a lot of organic search on those pages and we often get them back in stock. Thanks

You need to use a custom query to filter products by both stock status and size. You can learn more about creating a custom filter query and adding the custom filter functionality by following the documentation available here.  You'll find relevant examples to fix this on your website.
Please do share an update after making these updates to your website.
Note: Official WooCommerce product filter documentation is available here.
